# Web application page corrupt when running on IPad

Tags: ipad, web-applications, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap/cordova app. When i view the page in IPad (IOS6), as soon as the keyboard is up and i start typing, I get a weird behaviour:

1. sometimes the entire page starts jumping up and down
2. I get a big white space above the keyboard, so my page looks like it is cut in the middle.

This happens whether i run it on a browser or as a Phonegap app (which i guess is essentially the same).

Is that a known problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :)

Just add `min-height` that matches the page height:

```
#page{
 min-height: 700px;
}
```

and everything works like a charm.